# How to create a consistent forensic image from a live RHEL system?

Tags: rhel, lvm, disk-image, mirror, forensics

In our environment we have RHEL7 systems that need to be always up and running. I know the preferred method of acquiring a forensic image is to take the system offline, but in case of a live image, what would be the preferred method?

- A dd of the root file system to a separate partition would be inconsistent as files may change during the process
- Our systems use LVM, so maybe we can use lvconvert to mirror each lvol, take it out of the VG and then take a dd of it?
- Can we leverage software RAID 1 to create a mirror disk and then break it in some way?

It's important to note that it is not possible to install third party tools, everything should be done with RHEL7 default software.

Comment: This is naive at best. You can't take an accurate image of a live system. You also can't rely on the existing binaries to take the image. You must boot from an external medium before taking the image. For proper forensic accuracy there are also various procedures to follow, such as adding timestamps and cryptographic signatures to the images.

Comment: @SatoKatsura you ought to make that an answer

Comment: You can use LVM snapshots to get a consistent snapshot of a volume. At least as long as the system is cooperating (e.g., is not compromised) which as Sato Katsura points out, disqualifies it as a forensic image.

Comment: @Sato Katsura I agree, but in some situations it's more important to keep a system running than to have Forensic evidence. In such cases, you want to do a best effort. I believe a mirror can be fairly accurate, maybe if you provide a known good dd and lvm tools via USB for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get proper forensic image from running system.

After reading the question discussion... you can try to narrow down the issues count by calling "sync", remount all file systems in RO and get the file systems image. Better, if you have synchronized mirror, which you could remount in RO.